# One line Scala function to invert (Int => Boolean) function

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

## Question

If there a way in Scala to define the inv function below in one line?

```
// Function to invert a decision function such as even/odd/positive/...
def inv(f: Int => Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = {
    def g(a:Int):Boolean = {
        !f(a)
    }
    g
}

// Test
def even(x:Int):Boolean = (x % 2 == 0)
val odd = inv(even)
println("odd(99) is %s".format(odd(99)))
----
odd(99) is true
```

### Problem

Tried below with !f or !f(a) as below but got errors. Not sure what exactly is wrong. If explanation can be provided, it would be appreciated.

```
def inv(f: Int => Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = !f
----
error: value unary_! is not a member of Int => Boolean

def inv(f: a:Int => b:Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = !f(a)
----
error: ')' expected but ':' found.                                                                                                                                               
def inv(f: a:Int => b:Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = !f(a)     
            ^
```

Comment: In Scala, you can always write everything in one line: just remove the linebreaks (possibly replacing them with semicolons if necessary). E.g. your original example: `def inv(f: Int => Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = { def g(a:Int):Boolean = { !f(a) }; g }`. The question is: now that you have written it in one line, what did you actually gain from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
def inv(f: Int => Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = a => !f(a)
```

What's wrong with `!f`: `f` isn't a `Boolean`.

What's wrong with `def inv(f: a:Int => b:Boolean)`: When the parser looks at this definition, it knows that `f:` is going to be followed by a type. `a` can be a type, but it can't be followed by `:` in this case (`a:Int => b:Boolean` is not a type).

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the input parameter explicitly like in the example below, because your function returns another function:

```
def inv(f: Int => Boolean):(Int => Boolean) = x => !f(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understood the return value signature (Int => Boolean) needs to match with the implementation (= ...).